# Getting Statistical Summary of Entire Dataset Without Building Model

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Some people at my company are interested in exploring relationships between a lot of features in our data. There are around 40 or so features, and they want to know how they are related, the regression coefficients and p-values. I like the stats models OLS summary as it is in a concise format and does not require a lot of code since I will be running this many times, but I am not trying to build a model. I have only used stats models after splitting data into test and training sets in the past, but wondering if I can also use this for a summary of the entire data frame. I was just wondering if the below was a good way to get all p-values and coefficients for the entire data set (dependent variable is 2021 revenue)? I am not sure how to convert this to a data frame so I can share with others at my company, but it is easy to copy and paste.

```
y = df[['2021 Revenue']]

X = df[['Col_1', 'Col_2', 'Col_3', 'Col_4']]

import statsmodels.api as sm

lr_1 = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

lr_1.summary()
```

I just want to ensure that this would be the same output as if I were to calculate all of the p-values and coefficients independently since I am not fitting a model and have not used this otherwise.

Comment: What kind of coefficients and pvalues do you expect? The OLS summary is for a multiple regression model. The regression coefficients are based on partial correlation which will differ from regressing y on each x separately (unless all x are orthogonal to each other).

Comment: Reminder, statsmodels does not add an intercept (except when using formulas. The user provided X is used as is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Someone did a regression in excel or something else but has since left the company so trying to recreate in python, but in the most efficient way since it will just be used for exploratory purposes. The coefficients and p-values I got from the OLS summary differ from what the person did previously, but I am guessing that is because they regressed y on each x separately. Can you point me in the direction of how to create my own statistical summary in data frame format with all of the p-values, coefficients and intercept?